# Display output data from files in c++

Tags: c++, file, output

I'm doing a file function for my program and I want to make this program read the data that has been written from the file.
This is part of the data in my parking3.txt file:

CAR PARKING SYSTEM

The Car position in parking lot : B3

The Driver Name : amanda

The Car No : 1234

The Hours Of Stay : 4

CAR PARKING SYSTEM

The Car position in parking lot : A1

The Driver Name : malik

The Car No : 5678

The Hours Of Stay : 3

And here is part of my code for this function

```
void output() //details statement to the user
    {
        int i=0;
        cout<<Parking.area[i][i]<<endl;
        cout<<Parking.DriverName<<endl;
        cout<<Parking.VehicleNo<<endl;
        cout<<Parking.Hours<<endl;
    }


    
int main()
{
    cout << "\n\n\t\t== Viewing Record in the Parking Database ==";
    
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("parking3.txt",ios::in);
    cout << "\n";
    int i=0;
    infile>>Parking.area[i][i];
    infile>>Parking.DriverName;
    infile>>Parking.VehicleNo;
    infile>>Parking.Hours;
    output();
    system("PAUSE");
    
}
```

The problem is why when i run the program it shows

```
    The Car position in parking lot : CAR


    The Driver Name : PARKING


    The Car No : SYSTEM


    The Hours Of Stay : 0
```

How do I change my code so it will display all the data in my txt file when I run the code, just same as how I wrote it before in that txt file?

Comment: Have a look at [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) – you should read entire *lines* of the file and parse these, especially as you have spaces in between. Then you should skip very first line, then search in each subsequent line for the colon and only parse the part right afterwards.

Comment: Start small, extract a [mcve] where you just write a file and then manually verify it. Then, make another program to just read an existing file. Then, merge the two programs.

Comment: For the output you receive: Be aware that `operator>>` ignores any leading whitespace and then stops parsing at any white-space it discovers, so as the first three inputs are apparently objects of type `std::string` they get the first three words while on reading hours – presumably an integer type – the word `The` is tried to be parsed for, which fails, of course, resulting in setting the variable to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The computer doesn't know what you want.

This code reads the first word in the file. The first word is "CAR", so that's what it reads.

```
infile>>Parking.area[i][i];
```

Then this code

```
infile>>Parking.DriverName;
```

reads the second word in the file. The second word is "PARKING" so that's what it reads. And so on.

In your file the data that you want to read is mixed up with a lots of text that you want to ignore. So you need to invent some code that will do that, read the data you want, ignore the text that you don't. You aren't going to get any help from the computer with this. It's your job to write that code.

This seems like a very complicated (and pointless) problem for a beginner, My advice would be to change your file so that it is easier to read. For example, suppose your file looked like this

```
B3
amanda
1234
4
A1
malik
5678
3
```

Then the code you have written would work.

Make things easy for yourself, write the data file so that it is easy for a computer to read. It doesn't matter so much whether it is easy for a person to read.

Comment: @Aconcagua I would say that's pretty obvious from the context. Claiming that human readability is unimportant in general would be a pretty dumb thing to say.

Comment: Hm – OK, we might agree on that, though I've seen so many dumb people out there as well... But don't want to attribute that to the question author ;)